# Whats the shortest way to return a condition as 1 and -1

Tags: javascript

Is there any shorter way to return a condition as `1` if **true/truthy** and `-1` if **false/falsy**? Maybe using bitwise operators?

The shortest way I can think is:

```
condition?1:-1
```

Comment: You got it!  At least, that's my opinion...

Comment: Depends on what `condition` is. Without more details, the conditional operator you've used is the best choice.

Comment: What's the point in making this shorter? Imo it's already pretty compact. Even shorter than this means hack, harder to reason about and more error prone. And second, what are you going to do with this `1:-1` value? If you really need to shorten this, maybe there is another point to approach the problem.

Comment: @Thomas, it looks like the factor for sorting ...

Comment: Honestly, for clarity, your solution seems the best out of the short ones proposed. Saving a few characters is not worth the loss in cleanliness.

Comment: @NinaScholz in that case I'd go with `condition || -1` as the truthy condition would be converted to a `+1` anyway.

Comment: @Thomas For challenge purposes only, if you need to add to the variable (i + 1) or (i - 1) depending on the condition, I thought to myself theres gotta be a shorter way to do like:
i + (i%2==0?1:-1), or something...

Comment: This isn't [codegolf.SE]

Answer (score 4):

Just take

```
+condition || -1
```

where `condition` is a boolean value.

Comment: Good idea, but it's not shorter than the OP's code, which I would prefer for clarity

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `condition` is a boolean value, we can [golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) one character:

```
condition*2-1
```

<sup>(Not that I would recommend to write code like this…)</sup>

---

> there's gotta be a shorter way to do than `i + (i%2==0?1:-1)`

What you actually want is to just toggle the last bit in the number, which can be achieved with XOR:

```
i^1
```

Comment: Very nice! I wouldn't write code like this either, lol.

Answer (score 0):

I see those ones :

- (for the funny transformation)

```js
// #1
let boolToNumber = b=> +b*2-1;
// #2
boolToNumber = b => (b<<1)-1;
// #3
boolToNumber = b => b?+b:~b;
```

- And if what really matter for you is the size, make it an 1 char function

```js
// 
let boolToNumber = b=> +b*2-1;
let b = boolToNumber;
let c = true;
b(c)// 4 charaters
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can try the folowing:

```
condition ^ (condition - 1)
```

So when condition is true then that would be:

```
1 ^ (1 - 1)
 => 1 ^ 0
 => 1
```

And when condition is false then:

```
0 ^ (0 - 1)
=> 0 ^ -1
=> -1
```

Hope this helps.